# what is the preferred way to split test.java file into 2 files

Tags: checkstyle

My Test script file is more than 2000 lines and so results in checkstyle warning.
So I need to split my TestA.java file into 2 files. There is common code in the test cases. Could anyone suggest preferred way to do this?

Comment: [Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/9780132350884)

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest at least two patterns:

- Extract some common code to the separate classes and use them in the split tests
- Create abstract base test with shared functionality and inherit it in split test cases (simple, but risky approach as it is not possible to inherit behaviour from more than one abstract class)

Comment: I think your suggestions are valid if there is no underlying code-smell. +1.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the question

> Why is your test class long, not how you should split it.

The answer will likely lead to taking a good look at your target (the class under test) and you might find that it does too many things. That it may not adhere to Single Responsibility Principal.

If that is the case, you rearrange target, split your tests and kill 2 birds in one stone - Get rid of the CS warning and make your code better organized.

**Remember, CS's complaint about number of lines is a code smell. By splitting the file you might be covering it up, rather than cleaning it up.**

Of course if you are convinced that there is no problem with your design, you can certainly ignore the CS warning rather than creating an arbitrary file split.

Hope this helps.